# Why typescript does not compile destructured property children from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having a problem making this code

```
const AuthInit = (props: any) => {
    let {children: WithChildren} = props;
...
return showSplashScreen ? <LayoutSplashScreen /> : <>{children}</>
}
```

compile, I have to use `props.children` and remove the destructured line for it to work. Why is that? and how can I make it work

```
type WithChildren = {
  children?: ReactNode
}
```

> error: TS2304: Cannot find name 'children'.

Comment: You are destructuring into an alias, not giving a type annotation so your variable name is `WithChildren`. (also children is of type `ReactNode` not `WithChildren` according to your type)

Comment: At any rate, `let {children: WithChildren} = props;` means "take the `children` property from `prop` and assign it to the variable called `WithChildren`. Which is why `children` does not exist as a variable. It's just `let {children} = props;` to destructure the property `children`  to the variable `children`.